# How to read local sql file?

Tags: java, sql, file, filereader, matcher

I have downloaded SQL file and I want to read it without using some additional programs, only IDE. I have tried to read it like txt file but it didn't work.

When I use `System.out.print` to see the line output. it works, but when I try to use `Matcher` i have:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.CharSequence.length()" because "this.text" is null
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:415)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1134)
    at com.teleutsa.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

I suspect the problem is not in the file type but I am not sure. Thanks to anyone who would like to help.

```
    Set<String> emails = new HashSet<>();
    Pattern patter= Pattern.compile("regex");
    Matcher matcher = null;

    try {
        File file = new File("d://file.sql" );
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {

            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
            matcher = patter.matcher(line);
            while(matcher.find()){
                emails.add(matcher.group());

            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String e:emails) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the instruction `line = reader.readLine();` in the while loop, when you arrive at the end of the .sql file returns `null`.
For this reason you get this compile time error.
Just change the the order of the statement, like this:

```
    Set<String> emails = new HashSet<>();
    Pattern patter= Pattern.compile("regex");
    Matcher matcher = null;

    try {
        File file = new File("sample1.sql" );
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            matcher = patter.matcher(line); 
            while(matcher.find()){
                emails.add(matcher.group());
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String e:emails) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```